# Is it possible to require statically resolved type parameter to be a generic type?

Tags: f#

Having a hierarchy

```
open FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI.UnitSymbols

type Vector2D<[<Measure>] 'u>(x: float<'u>, y: float<'u>) =
   member val Abs = 
     let squared = float (x*x+y*y)
     LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'u> (Math.Sqrt squared)      

type R2D = 
    inherit Vector2D<m>(x, y)
    member val X = x
    member val Y = y

type V2D(vx, vy) = 
    inherit Vector2D<m/s>(vx, vy)
    member val Vx = vx
    member val Vy = vy       

type A2D(ax, ay) =
    inherit Vector2D<m/s^2>(ax, ay)
    member val Ax = ax
    member val Ay = ay
```

I would like to define global inline operator `(+) (l:^v) (r:^v)` where `^v` would be required to inherit from `Vector2D`, have some unit of measure `float<'u>` and *have constructor with two parameters of type `float<'u>`*.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to do define the add function and then assign it to infix operator:

```
let add<[<Measure>]'u, 'v when 'v :> Vector2D<'u>> (l:^v) (r:^v) = l.Abs + r.Abs

let (+) left right = add left right
```

**EDITED:**
This is how you can use it: 
IN this case left and right types has to match

```
let left = R2D(1.0<m>,1.0<m>)
let right = R2D(2.0<m>,2.0<m>)
let result = left + right
```

or you can try without matching types, still unit has to match

```
let left:Vector2D<m> = R2D(1.0<m>,1.0<m>) :> Vector2D<m>
let right:Vector2D<m> = A2D2(2.0<m>,2.0<m>) :> Vector2D<m>
let result = left + right
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I create instance of `^v` that is instance of resolved type?
something like `... = new v^(1<m>, 2<m>)`?

Comment: I am not sure you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a separate `+` for each subtype of `Vector2D` like so:

```
type V2D(vx, vy) = 
    inherit Vector2D<m/s>(vx, vy)
    member val Vx = vx
    member val Vy = vy
    static member (+) (l:V2D, r:V2D) = V2D(l.Vx + r.Vx, l.Vy + r.Vy)

type A2D(ax, ay) =
    inherit Vector2D<m/s^2>(ax, ay)
    member val Ax = ax
    member val Ay = ay
    static member (+) (l:A2D, r:A2D) = A2D(l.Ax + r.Ax, l.Ay + r.Ay)

let v1 = V2D(2.0<m/s>, 3.0<m/s>)
let v2 = V2D(2.0<m/s>, 3.0<m/s>)
v1 + v2 //yields in FSI: val it : V2D = FSI_0002+V2D {Abs = 7.211102551; Vx = 4.0; Vy = 6.0;}
```

You can `inline` them if you want for performance as well, and can define other mathematical functions the same way if you don't want to deal with polymorphism and/or typechecking.

Comment: Yes, that’s how I currently implemented it. But I always seek  more generic approach ;)